# Excel horizontal list to columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to format some data. To make it more easy I use an example with simple numbers.

```
Sheet 1 ('S1'):
A1 10 
A2 14 
A3 23 
A4 12 
A5 64 
A6 32
.... etc
```

It is a long list(vertical) of 600 values

Now I want in Sheet 2('S2'):

To show it as:

```
S1!A1 S1!A2 S1!A3 S1!A4 S1!A5 S1!A6
S1!A7 S1!A8 S1!A9 S1!A10 S1!A11 S1!A12
S1!A13 S1!A14 S1!A15 S1!A16 S1!A17 S1!A18
```

References to the cells in the other sheet.

I have tried to transpose them but I cannot find a modifier to set an amount of columns used. i.e. I would get 1 row with all my data. I want only the first 6 in row, next 6 in next row, next 6... etc.

Thanks for any help/feedback given.

Comment: See https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3360-excel-transpose-every-5-rows.html#a1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in the upper left cell desired:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*6+COLUMN(A:A))
```

Then copy/drag over 6 columns and down till you finish the list

[image: ![enter image description here]

Sheet1

[image]